# Issue in page navigation using jquery mobile in Windows Phone 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.

I have a sidebar menu for page navigation. As I am having same menu for multiple pages, I would like to keep it dynamic, i.e. generated in .js file.

Problem is: If I add the ul and li elements in html file, the links navigate to the respective pages properly. But when I append the ul and li elements in js file, the links are not responding.

Here is the code being used:

```
var ulStr = '<div class="ui-panel-inner">'+
                    '<header class="nav-header">MUSCLES</header>'+
                    '<ul id="leftMenu'+identifier+'" data-role="listview" class="sidelist ui-listview">'+
                        '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#Ch0C1" class="navlink ui-link-inherit" data-ajax="false">TERMINOLOGY</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>'+
                        '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#Ch0C2" class="navlink ui-link-inherit" data-ajax="false">page 2 name</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>'+
                        '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#Ch1C0" class="navlink ui-link-inherit" data-ajax="false">page 3 name</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                '</div>';

$('#leftNavmenu'+identifier).html("");
$('#leftNavmenu'+identifier).html(ulStr);
```

Same code is working properly in android and iOS platforms. SO there is not any possibility of syntax error. It would be great if someone would be able to help.

Comment: How are you creating the links on the elements?

Comment: Scroll the code section @Alvaro there are <a></a> elements inside li.

Comment: How are you dealing with the anchors with jQuery.

Comment: I have specified href in anchor. @Alvaro

Comment: What I'm asking is: what happens when you click the anchor. How you load the desired page, by jquery? if so, how?

Comment: The desired page should be loaded using href. But its not being loaded. @Alvaro I am not doing it dynamically like `changePage`. Using this approach: `<a href="#next_page_id">Page name</a>`

Comment: Yeah but, once the browser goes to #next_page_id, then how the page knows which page to load. How you tell it what to load. Because that will only redirect the user focus to the element with the id `next_page_id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47312/discussion-between-mystic-magic-and-alvaro)

Comment: you have `data-ajax="false"` added to links and you're using _multi-page model_, they shouldn't work on any device.

Comment: @Omar They are working fine in android and ios. What is the issue in that? I am a learner, so not sure what's wrong :/

Comment: you several `data-role=page` in one file right?

Comment: yes @Omar right. So what's wrong with `data-ajax = "false"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile's *Navigation* is based on *Ajax* and *hashchange*. When you disabled *Ajax* (`data-ajax="false"`), browser instead looks for div with *id* referred from *anchor* tag.

As mentioned in your OP, it works on iOS and Android. It is because `hashchange` event is triggered, hence, transition occurs. However, if you disable `hashListeningEnabled`, It won't work on any device with *Ajax* disabled.

Use `data-ajax="false"` when you want to load an *external* page via HTTP not *Ajax*. It has the same effect of `rel="external"`.